# Rectangular divs with textual content are arranged in rows based on their sort order

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, sorting, jquery-plugins, html

Is it possible to create the following behavior with one or more existing JQuery plugin(s)/widget(s)... or with some other web framework?

Rectangular divs with textual content are arranged in rows (left to right) based on their sort order, and then flow to the next line if needed (top to bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `float: left` on each `<div>`.

Comment: Gosh, that takes care of it.  I didn't realize that it would be so simple.

Comment: I tried to accept it when I left the comment... but it didn't let me.